# DataGridView linked with DataTable not showing data ODBC

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, odbc

I have a datatable filled using an OdbcAdapter. I know for a fact that this table has data in it because if I put a break point I see that it has 5 columns and a count of 852.

I tried putting this table as the data source of a bindingsource then attaching this bindingsource to a DataGridView as well as setting the table as the DataGridView's source directly.

In both cases, the gridview has 0 rows in it and displays nothing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
private void populateTable() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM MASKENCODE";
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, Program.myConnection);


        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, Program.myConnection);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);

        table.DefaultView.AllowDelete = false;
        table.DefaultView.AllowEdit = false;
        table.DefaultView.AllowNew = false;
        //table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
        //bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("TABLE EXISTS");
        }
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("GRID EXISTS");
        }
}
```

I always get the "TABLE EXISTS" print but not the "GRID EXISTS" one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true mainly in designer file. If not add the below line of code to automatically generate columns.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Comment: Perfect! that fixed things.